# Username in URL for Django User Profile

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7, user-profile

I have a Django project that uses profiles for user information. Things are somewhat working except for one aspect... Here are code snippets to describe my problem.

In the template:

```
<li><a href="/accounts/{{ user.username }}/profile/">Profile</a></li>
```

In views.py

```
class UserProfileView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, user):
        profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'profile': profile})
```

In urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<user>.+)/profile/$', 
    UserProfileView.as_view(),  
    name='user_profile_view'
),
```

I've tried variations for the named group, and this is what I found to work. The problem is, I can use any string in between `/accounts/` and `/profile/` (obviously) and it works. What I want to accomplish is to have only the current user's username be valid in the URL and otherwise throw a `404`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the user parameter in the profile URL? If you only want it work for the current user, then why not simply drop the `user` parameter:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^accounts/profile/$', 
    UserProfileView.as_view(),  
    name='user_profile_view'
),

# views
class UserProfileView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request):
        profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'profile': profile})
```

In the code you posted, the `UserProfileView.get` method was not using the `user` parameter anyway.

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep the `user` parameter and make it work the way you want, you can change the view like this:

```
from django.http import Http404

class UserProfileView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, user):
        if request.user.username == user:
            profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
            return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'profile': profile})
        else:
            raise Http404
```

Btw, since `user` in the parameter list of the `get` method is really just the username as opposed to a user object, it would be better to rename it to `username`, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure why I added the user parameter in the view; it may have been in trying different options (I've removed it). But to your point, I don't have to use the `username`, but I thought it would be more descriptive. What would be the way to do this?

Comment: @nicorellius if I understood you correctly, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks - that looks great. What would be the correct URLConf code such that the URL would be `/accounts/<username>/profile/`?

Comment: @nicorellius your current one should work. Or you could make it a bit more strict, like `^accounts/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/profile/$`

Comment: That did it - thanks a bunch! PS - as you pointed out, it didn't work with `username`, threw error about `get()` not liking `username` parameter. This is the URL named group I used: `^accounts/(?P<user>[\w-]+)/profile/$`